# How to position text ontop of an Image Label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been tinkering with Tkinter the last couple of days to create a little game.

I have searched for how to display text ontop of an image label but there is a little downside, it won't display exactly at the spot i am looking(in this case the top left side of the label).

[image: This is the current label I am working on and how it is displayed.]

I tried anchor and compound together in the same label but it doesn't seem to do anything new
the text still remains in the middle.

The code looks like this:

```py
'''Adjusting the information frame'''
self.image_info = PhotoImage(file=locate_images("_info_panel", ""))
self.label_text_info = "• Welcome to Agony,\nto play or read the rules please go to File"
self.label_info = Label(self.info, text=self.label_text_info, font=10, image=self.image_info, compound=CENTER, anchor=NW)
self.label_info.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

**Edit:**
If I try to add anything else other than `compound=CENTER` the text is displayed outside the boundingbox of the image on the specified side.

Comment: Could you show some code which you've tried but hasn't worked out?

Comment: Actually that's about all the code i've tried since i cannot seem to find anything regarding this. I have looked through all the label commands but still couldnt find anything

Comment: Did you try `compound=BOTTOM`?

Comment: I did try compound=BOTTOM but all it does is display it ontop of the image instead of inside. 
According to one stackoverflow post anchor cannot display text on the screen corectly if you don't explicitly state the width/height of a label but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In this case, you need to separate the text and image into two labels.  But then the text will not have transparent background.  Or use Canvas.

Comment: I tried it and it didnt have the white background, but i still couldn't position it at the topleft side.
self.label_image_info = Label(self.info, image=self.image_info, width="300px", height="600px")
self.label_text_info = Label(self.info, text=self.label_text_info, font=10)
self.label_image_info.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.label_text_info.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW)
http://prntscr.com/qjyj35

Comment: You need to get the position of the image, then use `place(...)` instead of `grid(...)` to put the text at the top left corner of the image.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for the suggestion after i tried it with a canvas i got it to work.
Also how do i close a case and upvote an answer?
It's my first post in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

*Moved from an edit to the question by the OP to an answer.*

Use a `Canvas`:

```
'''Adjusting the information frame'''
self.image_info = PhotoImage(file=locate_images("_info_panel", ""))
self.label_text_info = "• Welcome to Agony,\nto start the game or read the rules please go to File"
self.canvas_info = Canvas(self.info, width=300, height=600)
self.canvas_info.create_image((0, 0), image=self.image_info, anchor=NW)
self.canvas_info.create_text((140, 25), text=self.label_text_info)
self.canvas_info.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

> I was approaching it wrong from the start, I am fearly new to tkinter
> and I had to use a canvas to display the items inside of.